# С помощью regex из ФИО сделать фамилию и инициалы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, текст, split

Есть список ФИО:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович, Петров Петр Петрович, Ахмед Хасан
```

из него нужно сделать:

```
Иванов И.И., Петров П.П., Ахмед Х.
```

пробовал я лишнее отрезать таким регекспом, безрезультатно.

```
(?:^[А-Яа-яіє']*)|[^\sА-ЯІЇЄ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Regex, но на мой вкус, с ними сложнее, менее читабельно,  и, как я подозреваю, дольше. Я, впрочем, не большой спец по регекспам, и наверняка кто-то может предложить более изящное решение.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class So_755361 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Иванов Иван Иванович, Петров Петр Петрович, Ахмед Хасан, " 
                    + " ,, Сидоров    степан   иваныч  , Kennedy J. F.,  ИванДурак," 
                    + " еще ктото ,  ,, ";

  say("Способ 1, без регэкспов");
    String[] ss = input.split(",");
    for (String s: ss) {
        if ((s = s.trim()).isEmpty()) continue; 
        String[] sss = s.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sss[0] + " ");
        for (int i = 1; i < sss.length; i++)
            if (!(s = sss[i].trim()).isEmpty()) 
                sb.append(s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + ".");
        say("  " + sb.toString());
    }

  say("\nСпособ 2, с регекспами:");
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("^\\s*([\\wА-Яа-я]+)"
            + "(\\s+([\\wА-Яа-я]?)\\S*)?(\\s+([\\wА-Яа-я]?)[\\wА-Яа-я]*.*)?");
    ss = input.split(",");
    for (String s: ss) {
        if ((s = s.trim()).isEmpty()) continue;
        Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            say("  " + m.group(1) + " "  
                     + (m.group(3) == null? "" : (m.group(3).toUpperCase() + "."))
                     + (m.group(5) == null? "" : (m.group(5).toUpperCase() + ".")));
        }
    }
}

static public void say(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
    String fio = "Иванов Иван Иванович, Петров Петр Петрович, Ахмед Хасан";
    String fio1 = fio.replaceAll("([^,] .)[^ ]+", "$1.").replaceAll("(\\.) (.)[^, ]+", "$1$2.");
    System.out.println(fio1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон довольно прост получился, 3 группы, в первую полностью фамилию, во вторую и третью заглавные символы имени и отчества соответственно, третья группа необязательная.

```
(\p{L}+)\s(\p{Lu})\p{L}+(?:\s(\p{Lu})\p{L}+)?
```

использовать replaceALL на

```
$1 $2.$3.
```

---

Минус который я сейчас вижу, это в случае отсутствия отчества все равно ставится точка, наверное можно "закостылить" на проверку двух точек, но думаю решение должно быть и лучше.

Comment: Почему не `\w`?

Comment: @Alex78191 `\w` - эквивалентно `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, если добавлять ключ `u` - для поддержи юникода, то `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`, так же на `\w` не получится поставить регистр

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи не стоит использовать regex
Самый простой и правильный вариант будет просто разбить по пробелам строку и склеить ее обратно

```
String[] arr = input.split(" ");
String answer = arr[0];
for ( String str : arr.subList( 1, arr.size() ) )
{
   answer.concat(" ");
   answer.concat(str.substring(0, 1);
   answer.concat(".");
}
```

Comment: Нет ответа на вопрос! Во первых, для начала нужно разбить строку по пробелам, на отдельные ФИО, а только потом каждую запись уже бить по вашему способу. Ну и все это потом нужно опять в строку собрать

Answer (score 0):

Разбейте строку через `split` по запятым, а потом к каждой записи из полученного массива можно регулярку применить `^([\w]+) (\w{1}).* (\w{1}).*$`, берем данные из регулярки и собираем строку как Вам нужно, и добавляем каждую запись в новый массив, после чего этому массиву делаем `join` с символом разделителя фамилий, в данном случае запятая.